# Backlight rim effect on hair in vanilla Blender

Tags: light, hair

Was trying to make a semi realistic head. Felt like the head hairs could use some rim light, so I made the backlight... and now I am stalled for quite a while.

This image sums what I mean as backlight effect:
[image]

The things I tried are:

•Mix translucent shader. All the hair becomes kinda transparent

•Fiddle with fresnel. The effect happens on all hairs at the same time, not only the ones on the edge

•Shaders with white base + mix shaders + fresnel as FAC. Not quite

•Translucent shader + mix shader + layer waight for FAC. The best I could do. But makes hairs appear to be in a semi-transparent flat plane

•One other thing I thought could work but I didn't try yet is polygon hair + SSS

I gave up on trial and researched. Apparently there's a way to do it
[image]

Here is an example of a tool called Fibermesh, but it's not for Blender I guess. Then I found out there's a tool for blender to make very nice hairs, the Strand Rendering. Found out about it here:
https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?274660-Cycles-Strand-Rendering/page56

The thing is, I want to make the backlight on hair effect in vanilla Blender, aka official build with no pluggins. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I think it may just be a matter of correctly placing the backlight in relation to the camera. Translucency might also not be necessarily required, mabe adding some gloss to the hair material will suffice to make light bouce around the particles and make some highlights

Comment: I would first move that wall further back. You will need that space to add a light almost directly behind your model. I would also turn off all other lights (so you can easily see what you are doing) and just focus on getting the back light perfect.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks for the tips. I've tested gloss b4 to no good result at all. I used translucency because works for vellus hairs. The downside is the transparency in addition to the backlight effect. Also, faking the effect is no option for this project. The hair should really glow white when between a strong light and the cam.

Comment: @icYou520 Ehrrrmm... my model is the one on top right corner... the last image I found somewhere just to illustrate :P. And, also, thanks for the tips. Very appreciated